# Exceção de stack overflow sendo gerada no método de instância "Equals()"

Tags: c#, .net, herança, ciclo-infinito, equals

Criei uma classe chamada `MyList<T>`, com a intenção de reproduzir a classe `List`, e sobrescrevi o método `Equals` para comparar sua instância com outra da mesma classe, da seguinte forma:

```
class MyList<T> {
    
    // Código da classe...

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        
        if (obj is MyList<T>) {
            return Equals(obj, this);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Equals(MyList<T> listA, MyList<T> listB) {

        if (listA.Count != listB.Count) {
            return false;
        }
        for (long i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++) {
            if (!listA[i].Equals(listB[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

O problema é que sempre que eu tento verificar se uma lista é igual a outra, o método de instância `Equals()` entra em um loop infinito e gera `StackOverflowException` com a seguinte *traceback*:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 35393 times:
--------------------------------
   at MyList`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Equals(System.Object)
   at System.Object.Equals(System.Object, System.Object)
--------------------------------
   at MyList`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Equals(System.Object)
   at TestCSharp.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Se eu utilizar apenas o método estático `Equals()`, passando as duas instâncias de `MyList<T>`, a verificação ocorre normalmente. Dito isso, creio que o problema esteja no método de instância.

```
Console.WriteLine(MyList<string>.Equals(list, list2)); // Retorna true ou false
Console.WriteLine(list.Equals(list2));                 // Stack Overflow
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Onde está a causa do *loop* infinito?

Comment: Tem algum motivo para estar utilizando `long`? `List.Count` é `int`...

Comment: @LuizFelipe Eu sei, mas eu quis minha propriedade como `long` com a intenção da minha lista poder conter mais elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método de instância está chamando o método errado pelas regras de resolução de sobrecarga. Esse método está recebendo um objeto do tipo `Object` e está passando para um método que espera `Object`, portanto não é o método estático `Equals()` que você escreveu ali na classe, já que ele espera um `MyList` e não um `Object`, Para resolver isso você tem que garantir que a chamada seja feito com um objeto `MyList`, fazendo um *cast*.

Isto é uma pena porque a versão 1.0 do C# não tinha mecanismos adequados e agora paga um preço eterno por isso, no 2.0 passou ter o mecanismo certo, mas era tarde demais.

Teste:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = new MyList<int>();
        var y = x;
        WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
    }
}

class MyList<T> {
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        WriteLine("instância");
        if (obj is MyList<T>) {
            return Equals((MyList<T>)obj, this);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Equals(MyList<T> listA, MyList<T> listB) {
        WriteLine("estático");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JyXAeC). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9keh3O). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/OverloadResolution.cs).

Como otimização poderia verificar se as referências são iguais, assim não precisa verificar algo custoso. Em geral não se aconselha criar um método que será adotado pelo operador de igualdade que pode potencialmente levar horas para executar.

Comment: A que mecanismos você se refere?

Comment: Principalmente Generics.